# C# How do I do a Try Catch Finally without a bool to free up resources?

Tags: c#, try-catch, try-catch-finally

I'm trying to do a try-catch-finally so that if the mainLog was successfully created, but an exception was thrown after that, it will be disposed of properly. However, if mainLog was *not* successfully created and there exists a `mainLog.Dipose()` method call, there will be *another exception*. Typically, I would do an if statement but `DocX.Create()` does not return a bool so I'm not sure how to do this. Thank you.

```
public static string Check_If_Main_Log_Exists_Silent()
    {
        DocX mainLog;
        string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yy") + ".docx";
        string filePath = @"D:\Data\Main_Logs\";
        string totalFilePath = filePath + fileName;

        if (File.Exists(totalFilePath))
        {
            return totalFilePath;
        }
        else if (Directory.Exists(filePath))
        {
            try
            {
                mainLog = DocX.Create(totalFilePath);
                mainLog.Save();
                mainLog.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The directory exists but the log does not exist and could not be created. " + ex.Message, "Log file error");
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                mainLog = DocX.Create(totalFilePath);
                mainLog.Save();
                mainLog.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The directory and log does not exist and could not be created. " + ex.Message, "Log file error");
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                if(mainLog)
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: `using (var mainLog = DocX.Create(totalFilePath)) { mainLog.Save(); }`.

Comment: you should simplify to keep your code try - use a temp variable for the message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/yh598w02.aspx) will call dispose only if it's null at the end of the code block. It's one of those handy syntactic sugars.

Answer (score 4):

In the general case you set `mainLog` to `null` by default and only call the method if it is not null. With C# 6 you can use the handy form:

```
mainLog?.Dispose();
```

For older versions a simple if:

```
if (mainLog != null)
    mainLog.Dispose();
```

If the object implements the `IDisposable` interface then using `using` is the simplest way as Gaspa79's answer shows.